# How to get lock timeout in hibernate with PostgreSQL database

Tags: spring, database, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to get lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) timeout in Spring Data JPA with PostgreSQL Server. I tried `@QueryHints` but postgres seems to ignore it.

```
@QueryHints(value = {@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "0")})
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("select s from Student s where s.email = :email")
Optional<Student> findWithForUpdate(@Param("email") String email);
```

With lock timeout value is 0, it appends NOWAIT with `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and lock command immediately timeout if there is already lock present.

if I set some other value for `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` lets say "20" it does not timeout.

Comment: You need to run `set lock_timeout = ...;`  before running SELECT FOR UPDATE to change the lock timeout

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Where should run this statement from database client or jpa or hibernate ? If I run this command from db client then it would be valid for that session, Can I make this query specific ? Or Is it possible to run from hibernate before running query ?

Comment: It affects the current session (=connection). You probably need to run that through a native query or something like that. Hibernate does a good job in exploiting database specific features.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I am not sure if pg-driver supports custom lock timeout from hibernate. Postgres is supporting for update nowait but it ignores custom lock_timeout values. Maybe I am asking too much ? But Do you have some handy examples for it ? Thanks.